# IIS reset fails after updating .NET framework

Tags: iis, .net

After I uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 and installed Visual Studio 2010 RC, executing IISRESET gives the following error message:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\VC>iisreset /stop
>
> Attempting stop... Stop attempt
>   failed. The system cannot find the
>   file specified. (2147942402, 80070002)

Further information :

Before beta2, the same computer also had beta1 installed. The OS is Windows 2008 Web Server

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?

Comment: Yeah, but it's so long ago that I can't remember what I did. I think that I the application pool was not updated to use the correct version of .NET, so I had to change that. But, I can't remember for sure

Answer (score 0):

May be a long shot, but I have resolved many of these issues by manually running [aspnet_regiis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.80).aspx) from the Framework directory that is causing me issues. There is a separate version of the tool in each of the Framework directories... usually with a root of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework.....

Comment: Thanks for the try, but it didn't help.

Comment: @Pete - Is there anything logged in the Event Log that would give a clue was to what file it thinks is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel -> Programs and select Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, click on uninstall or change and then select Repair  in the installation form.

The progress may take a lot of time, and you will have to restart the server, but after the process you will be able to execute iisreset succesfully again.